# Journeys from Gujarat in India to Dare es Salaam in what was then, Tanganyika in 1925 and 1948

Tags: india, british-empire, colonization, africa, ships

I am researching a journey for a novel where my character travels from Gujarat in India to Dare es Salaam in what was then, Tanganyika. The journey happens in 1925 and then again in 1948. Does anyone know of any descriptive accounts; where the ship might have stopped, conditions?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: The traditional trade route from East Africa to India followed the coast (Aden, Southern Persia, down the West coast of India). But by the time you are asking about there were presumably ships that could take the direct route across the Indian Ocean. Perhaps someone knows more.

Answer (score 1):

A large number of Indians came to East Africa from Gujarat in the 19th and early 20th centuries. A smaller number came to modern [Tanzania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indians_in_Tanzania) than to Uganda or Kenya.

The reason for the larger number to the other two countries was the importation of laborers for the building of the Kenyan Ugandan railroad. The ones who went to Tanzania were mostly traders, which is to say that they travelled in relative comfort ("business class" if not first class) on the ships of the time.